# Is it possible to pipe with cd command

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to pipe cd commands?

For example, I want to go into a directory and then use a file command on it's contents but when I type `cd x | file *` it just does the file command on my current directory and it doesn't change directory at all.

Comment: what shell are you using? if its bash just replace the pipe with  `&&`, or a semicolon if you don;t care to validate that the cd worked before running the file command. cd doesn't really produce output, so its not really useful to use it with pipes or redirections. your file statment should probably change to `file .\*`

Comment: This question is not possible to answer without knowing what shell you are using.

Answer (score 3):

A pipeline takes the output of one command
and uses it as the input to another command. 
So there are two problems with what you tried.

1. The `cd` command doesn’t produce any output<sup>1</sup>.
2. `file *` doesn’t take any input. 
   You might say, “Of course it takes input; it reads (part of) all the files.” 
   But it doesn’t read ***standard** input.* 
   If you type `file *`, it just runs and gives you its output;
   it doesn’t read anything from the keyboard.

What you want is `cd x; file *`,
to do the `cd` and then the `file *`.

As you may realize, that command line will *leave you*
in directory *`x`.* 
So an alternative is

```
(cd x; file *)
```

which runs the `cd` and the `file` in a subshell. 
The working directory of your main shell won’t change. 
A drawback of that is that,
if the command line sets any shell variables
or otherwise changes the shell’s state,
that will also affect only the subshell and not the main shell.

As Frank Thomas [pointed out in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1657455/is-it-possible-to-pipe-with-cd-command/1657461#comment2537359_1657455),
this is a somewhat naïve and sloppy answer. 
If the `cd` command fails, it will run `file *` in the current directory. 
A better answer is `cd x && file *`,
which you can read as “`cd x`
***and then*** do `file *`”. 
This will do the second command (`file *`)
only if the first command (`cd x`) succeeds. 
Also, it is safer to say `file -- *`
or `file ./*` rather than `file *`,
in case the directory contains any files whose names begin with **`-`**.

________________
<sup>1</sup> Well, sometimes it outputs the directory name.

Comment: it really depends on which shell the OP is using, because in cmd `()` doesn't start a subshell at all, and in powershell it's just used for grouping expressions

Comment: (1) AFAICT, there is no `file` command natively in CMD or PowerShell, so the question is obviously about Unix-like systems.  Is there any shell on a Unix-like system where my answer is wrong?  (2) Your comment, while not (strictly) *wrong,* is somewhat misleading — parentheses are used for grouping in CMD also.

Comment: it's entirely possible to install GNU file or any POSIX tools on Windows. And yes, I know `()` groups commands in cmd but it doesn't create a subshell